# Play video in iPhone using HTML5 and UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html5-video

I am writing a small POC to play the video in iPhone app. I would like to do so in UIWebView with the help of HTML5. I dont want to use standard players like AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController.

Can someone throw some light on it?..
I am new to this HTML5 environment on iPhone. So, any help to start this POC would be appriciated.

I forget to add that i would like to play h264 live stream on server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this:http://tetontech.wordpress.com/2009/08/28/html-5-video-and-audio-in-uiwebview-and-webview/

Comment: Thanks Mudit..But I forget to mention that i would like to see live stream using that player.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that:

```
NSString *bundleDirectory = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mov" ofType:nil];
NSString *filePath = [bundleDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"loopvideo.html"];
NSString *HTMLData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.web loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:bundleDirectory]];
```

In your HTML, you can embed the `<video>` tag and it should play.